# How does phase spectrum compensation works?

Tags: phase, speech-processing

I'm trying to find some information that explains how phase spectrum compensation of non-stationary signals methods works, but I can't find an exact description of the procedure. I can't understand what transformation do the phase of the noise signal undergoes. And how exactly does it depend on the SNR?

I would appreciate it if anyone could refer me to some reading material on the subject or just help me out with a brief explanation. it's just for my interest so I'm not looking for a very deep explanation

Thank you very much!

Comment: This short paper lays it out pretty clear. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/29469497_Noise_Driven_Short_Time_Phase_Spectrum_Compensation_Procedure_for_Speech_Enhancement

Comment: @Max thank you very much for your comment. After reading the article, there's one thing I'm not sure of: how were they able to estimate the DSTFT magnitude of the noise? i.e. $$ |D\hat (n,k)| $$ thank you once again for your help

Comment: Usually, this is done by looking at the speech pauses and the estimation is done adaptive.